# Can I use a "CC-BY" licensed 3D model in my commercial IPhone app?

Tags: ios, licensing, app-store

I'm working on an iphone game these days, since I am not good at 3D modeling, I download some useful "CC-BY" licensed 3D model from blendswap.com. I have rendered them into some 2D sprites form and use these sprites in my gmme. 
Is this legal? 
If this is legal, how should I "credit" the model's original author in my game? Should I add a "About"/"Credit" button on the game's main menu?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working on an iphone game these days, since I am not good at 3D modeling, I download some useful "CC-BY" licensed 3D model from blendswap.com.

Blendswap [supports multiple creative commons licenses](http://www.blendswap.com/licenses/) including CC-BY.

> I have rendered them into some 2D sprites form and use these sprites in my game.
> Is this legal?

CC-BY is a copyright license and a standardized way to give the public permission to share and use of creative works. Under it ([link taken from Blendswap](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)) you are allowed to use it and make modifications to it under specific conditions:

> **You are free**:
>
> - **to Share** — to copy, distribute and transmit the work
> - **to Remix** — to adapt the work
>   to make commercial use of the work

Turning the 3D model into into 2D sprites is a remix. You are allowed to do that, yes.

> If this is legal, how should I "credit" the model's original author in my game? Should I add a "About"/"Credit" button on the game's main menu?

Yes, but there are some conditions:

> - **Attribution** — You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work).

And you need to understand that:

> **Notice** — For any reuse or distribution, you must make clear to others the license terms of this work. The best way to do this is with a link to [this web page](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/).

So in your game credits you should give attribution.

Blendswap [coins it this way](http://www.blendswap.com/licenses/):

> This license lets others distribute, remix, tweak, and build upon your work, even commercially, as long as they credit you for the original creation. This is the most accommodating of licenses offered, in terms of what others can do with your works licensed under Attribution.
>
> This license grants everybody in the world (where applicable by law) permission to use a blend for any purpose, even commercial, but under an Attribution requirement, that is, the original author asks to be credited for the blend in the derivative works of the work users. If a user of the blend will not credit the original author the user has no permission to use the blend.

They don't give much suggestion for in-game use, however like a movie has a credits scroll (where they suggest to give credits in case of a movie), a game normally has something similar. Place credits there. Also tell under which license you've used the model and tell which model.

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes--that's legal. It's pretty much the entire point of the Creative Commons, especially that particular CC license. As long as the license doesn't include the NC (non-commercial) or ND (no derivatives) clauses, your use in this way should be fine.

An About page is a very common place to include appropriate credit for this.

Note that the terms of CC-BY require you to give credit in the manner that the copyright holder requests. If the copyright holder didn't make any concrete requests when they presented the license under which you downloaded the model, a best effort would probably include the author's name, and mention of the CC-BY license under which you're using the work, and a link to where others could find the model.

Comment: Next to attribution / credits, you need to make clear, what the license of that work is you make use of. *"For any reuse or distribution, you must make clear to others the license terms of this work. "* [CC-BY 2.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/)